Socle of the field of fractions

Let $C$ be an integral domain that is not a field, and let $L$ be its field of fractions.
I want to prove that $\mathrm{Soc}(L) = 0$, where we think about $L$ as a $C$-module.

The definition of a scole I am using is the intersection over all essential submodules of $L$.
Trying to prove this, I first took the case where $C = \mathbb{Z}$ and $L = \mathbb{Q}$.
In this case, for every $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, the submodule $k \mathbb{Z}$ is an essential submodule of $L$: if $H$ is any other non-empty submodule of $L$, then $a/b \in H$, and $kb \times a/b = ka$ is in both $H$ and $k \mathbb{Z}$. The intersection of all these essential submodules is clearly zero.
For the general case, I thought of applying the same logic: $C$ is not a field, so it has some non-unit $x \in C$.
Same reasoning as before gives that both $C$ and $xC$ are (different) essential submodules.
If the intersection is only zero, we are done. Otherwise, there must be a non-unit non-zero element in $y \in C \setminus xC$, and then just proceed as before.
The problem I have here is how do I know that the intersection is zero? in the previous case it was fairly obvious, but now it's unclear to me.
Edit thanks to a comment of Geoffrey Trang: any principal ideal is an essential module, and the intersection of these is zero if $C$ is not a field: if $x \in \cap_{a\in C} aC$, then $x \in x^2C$, which means $x$ is invertible. Now for any other $y \in C$, $x \in yC$, which means $x = yc$, multiplying by $x^{-1}$ shows that $y$ is also invertible, hence $C$ is a field.

The intersection of all nonzero principal ideals of an integral domain that is not a field is always zero.

@GeoffreyTrang Thanks, I edited with your answer.

You can post it as an answer. It's ok to post answers to your question and then even accept it.

Notice however that $x^2 \mid x$ does not imply that $x$ is invertible. It might happen that...

@MartinBrandenburg $x=0$
